# ownProps always passed as an empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have all my component wrapped in react redux and I am trying to render some component from another component by clicking to some button but I am not able to get the passed props

this is the code where I am trying to render a child component with some props:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ChildComponent from './child_component';

class Home extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }
 go_to_child_component(){
  this.setState({
    child_component_triggered: true
  })
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    {this.state.child_component_triggered ? <ChildComponent filter="some_value" /> : null}
    <button onClick={this.go_to_child_component.bind(this)}>render ChildComponent</button>
   </div>
  )
 }
 const mapStateToProps= (state) => {...//normal codes}
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {...//normal codes}
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

this is where I am trying to get the passed props in the child component by ownProps:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ChildComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }
 render() {
   return (
    <div> i am child component </div>
   )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(ownProps) // always {}
  let obj = {...state};
  obj.ownProps = {...ownProps};
  return {...obj};
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {...//normal codes}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildComponent);
```

ownProps is always empty object, any help please

Comment: You're not using `connectAdvanced` are you? Or overriding any of the redux methods?

Comment: i am just using connect in all of my components

Comment: I've been thinking about this and I'm stumped. Can you post more code? Or ideally, provide a git repo. I'd be happy to check it and test.

Comment: i updated the code

Comment: Which `react-redux` version are you using?

Comment: "react-redux": "^5.0.7",

Comment: Hmm I also am having this problem.

Comment: Incase anyone else finds there way here in the same way I did, I had not thought through what I was doing and expected state to be in ownProps, though they are very different things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.props.filter without maping in your child component

Comment: but I want to use store variables too, this does not work if I want to access the store,